# Java: divide two BigInteger Objects into a BigDecimal object

Tags: java, biginteger, bigdecimal

What is the easiest way, using the least amount of unnecessary overhead to divide two BigInteger objects and store it in a BigDecimal Object?

I have been trying to work around the problem and cannot find anything that does not use an extremely excessive amount of conversions.

Edit: Realized how stupid this question was, I'll leave it up for reference though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can convert your BigIntegers into BigDecimals:

```
// bigIntX is a BigInteger
BigDecimal bigDecX = new BigDecimal(bigIntX);
BigDecimal bigDecY = new BigDecimal(bigIntY);

// to divide:
bigDecX.divide(bigDecY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert both `BigInteger` to `BigDecimal` and then divide them.

see: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.math.BigInteger)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal)